# How to solve a linear programming problem

Tags: optimization, linear-programming

This is a simple problem, but being uninitiated, I need get some guidance on how to solve.

> Minimize: $x + 6y$
>
> Constraints: $$x + y = 10000 \\ x\leq 6995 \\ \frac y p \leq 746 \\ p\leq 12\\x,y\geq 0$$
>
> Where $p\in \mathbb Z$

Comment: At the objective function the coefficient of x is smaller than the coefficient of y. Therefore x has to be as large as possible, which is $x^*=6995$, And $y^*=10000-6995=3005$. $p$ can be any integer, which satisfy the condition $\frac{3005}{p} \leq 746$ and $p\leq 12$.

Comment: Thank you so much for your response.

Comment: You´re welcome. Any further questions ?

Comment: No more questions as such. Your answer is very clear. Thanks again.